# Error while running Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, bigbluebutton

I am trying to run Gradle on a project with following Gradle configurations;

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

task resolveDeps(type: Copy) {
    into('lib')
    from configurations.default
    from configurations.default.allArtifacts.file
}

/*
 * Seems like we need this here and in the sub-projects section for testng to resolve.
 * (ralam Oct 4, 2009)
 */
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver()) {
         name = 'remote'
        returnFirst = true
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "googlecode"
            addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
        }
           add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "blindside-repos"
            addArtifactPattern "http://blindside.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://blindside.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
        }            
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "maven2-central"
            m2compatible = true
            addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
        }  
    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "testng_ibiblio_maven2"
            m2compatible = true
            addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision])-jdk15.[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision])-jdk15.[ext]"
        }  
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "netty-dependency"
            m2compatible = true
            addArtifactPattern "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
    }
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "spring-bundles"
            m2compatible = true
            addArtifactPattern "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        }    
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
            name = "Red5"
            m2compatible = true
            addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
            addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
        }
    mavenRepo name: "sonatype-snapshot", urls: "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    mavenRepo name: "sonatype-releases", urls: "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
    }
}

/****
 * NOTES
 *  1. You cannot use provideCompile here as gradle will complain. But you can use it in the sub-projects.
 */
dependencies {
  // Servlet
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5@jar'

  // Mina
  compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.8@jar'
  compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-integration-beans:2.0.8@jar'
  compile 'org.apache.mina:mina-integration-jmx:2.0.8@jar'

  // Spring 
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.8.RELEASE@jar' 
  compile  'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.8.RELEASE@jar'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.8.RELEASE@jar'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.8.RELEASE@jar'

    // Red5
    compile 'org/red5:red5-server:1.0.5-RELEASE@jar'
    compile 'org.red5:red5-server-common:1.0.5-RELEASE@jar'
    compile 'org.red5:red5-io:1.0.5-RELEASE@jar'

    // Logging
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2@jar'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2@jar'
    compile 'org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.9@jar'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.9@jar'
    compile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.9@jar'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.9@jar'

    // Needed for the JVM shutdown hook but needs to be put into red5/lib dir.
    // Otherwise we get exception on aop utils class not found.
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.0.8.RELEASE@jar'
    compile 'aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0@jar'

  // Testing
//  compile 'org.testng:testng:5.8@jar' 
  compile 'org.easymock:easymock:2.4@jar'

    compile project(':common')
  compile 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2@jar'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.1@jar' 

    // Libraries needed to run the scala tools
    scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.9.2'
    scalaTools 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2'

    // Libraries needed for scala api
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.9.2'

    compile 'net.lag:configgy:2.0.0@jar'

    //redis
    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:2.0.0'
    compile 'commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.6'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver()) {
             name = 'remote'
            returnFirst = true
            add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "googlecode"
                addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            }
               add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "blindside-repos"
                addArtifactPattern "http://blindside.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://blindside.googlecode.com/svn/repository/[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            }            
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "maven2-central"
                m2compatible = true
                addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
            }  
        add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "testng_ibiblio_maven2"
                m2compatible = true
                addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision])-jdk15.[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision])-jdk15.[ext]"
            }  
            add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "netty-dependency"
                m2compatible = true
                addArtifactPattern "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
        }
            add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                name = "spring-bundles"
                m2compatible = true
                addArtifactPattern "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
                addArtifactPattern "http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
            }        
        }
       mavenRepo name: "sonatype-snapshot", urls: "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
       mavenRepo name: "sonatype-releases", urls: "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
    }

    group = 'org.bigbluebutton'
    version = '0.9.0'
    manifest.mainAttributes(provider: 'bigbluebutton')
}
```

Settings.gradle

```
include 'applet', 'app', 'common'
```

Every time I run gradle in my terminal it raises following errors

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle' line: 17

    * What went wrong:
    Could not compile build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle'.
    > startup failed:
      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 17: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver 
       @ line 17, column 9.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver()) {
                 ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 20: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 20, column 13.
                    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                     ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 25: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 25, column 10.
                   add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                  ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 30: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 30, column 9.
             add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                 ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 36: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 36, column 9.
             add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                 ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 42: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 42, column 7.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
               ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 48: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 48, column 7.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
               ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 54: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 54, column 7.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
               ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 134: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver 
       @ line 134, column 10.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver()) {
                  ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 137: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 137, column 14.
                    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                      ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 142: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 142, column 11.
                       add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                   ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 147: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 147, column 10.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                  ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 153: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 153, column 10.
                add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                  ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 159: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 159, column 8.
                    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                ^

      build file '/Users/Umair/Desktop/projects/conference_platform/phase 2/ss_code/bigbluebutton-master/deskshare/build.gradle': 165: unable to resolve class org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver 
       @ line 165, column 8.
                    add(new org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.URLResolver()) {
                ^

      15 errors


    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.774 secs
```

I believe these errors have something to do with Ivy, but not really sure.

BTW - I am on a Mac OSX Yosemite.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @TezroSolutions i am also trying to integrate BigBlueButton in my android app....can u please suggest me working sample code link for Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where in the world did you find this `add` stuff to define your repositories?

Why aren't you doing it the way the [gradle documentation says](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:ivy_repositories)?

```
ivy {
    url "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository"
    layout "pattern", {
        artifact "[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
        artifact "[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]"
    }
}
```

I think you have to rework your entire repository definition. Because you got the maven central (that is already included by `mavenCentral()`) in there again.

Take a close look at the gradle documentation how the repositories are supposed to be defined. Most of the things you got there can be reduced to very simple maven remote repository definitions like you did for the two sonatype repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your response @nitram. I am using this community project https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/master/deskshare

Comment: I didn't write the Gradle configuration myself.

Comment: @TezroSolutions that may be so. This is still wrong. Maybe it was written for some ancient version of gradle?

Comment: I believe it's coming from here: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-to-ignore-missing-pom-parent-td1436133.html
It seems to be one of the top search results on Google!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue for an old legacy project that I recently started maintaining, and one where I don't have the time to upgrade the Gradle file. I found this question while Googling my error, so I thought that I would share my answer.

Basically, the problem for my case was that the legacy project used an outdated version of Gradle, whereas my own Gradle version on the `$PATH` was set to a later version. I was able to fix the problem by downgrading the Gradle version specified in my `~/.bash_profile` in the `$GRADLE_HOME` variable, and sourcing the file again.